# Flight Germany to China operated by Chinese airline, still cancelled?

Tags: china, klm, china-southern-airlines, covid-19

I have booked flight KLM 4303 from Frankfurt to Beijing. [All KLM flights to Beijing  have been suspended until 15 March 2020](https://www.klm.com/travel/nl_en/prepare_for_travel/up_to_date/flight_update/index.htm). But on my online ticket it says that my flight is operated by China Southern Airlines. **Does that mean that the flight will still take place?**

Comment: It is better to check with Airline customer care directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official Announcement from China Government:

> In light of the recent outbreak of the novel coronavirus (nCov), we
>   would like to inform you that Tianhe International Airport (WUH) in
>   Wuhan, Hubei Province, China is shut down to limit the possibility of
>   the virus to spread to other places. As for now, other Chinese
>   airports are still operating.

Due to this situation, there are a few consequences:

**If you have a flight ticket from/to Wuhan:** your flight is canceled until further notice. You are entitled to a full refund.

**If you have a flight ticket from/to other Chinese cities:** your flight is still operating, unless if there is an announcement from the airline about your flight.

**If you are arriving from China:** you will be subject to further screening at the destination airport as the authorities want to ensure the virus will not enter the country. Please bear the extra process for safety reasons.

You can simply check your flight status from China Southern Airlines too by putting your Booking Number or ticket number.

It will also show the status. In addition, simply call China Southern Airlines to confirm which is the best and reliable way in this situation.

Comment: I checked with the airline (Southern China) and it is in fact correct that the flight still takes place. Thank you!